# Live countdown timer in react

Tags: reactjs, timer, countdown

So I am trying to make a countdown timer which will work even if I exit page or refresh tab. I made a timer its works correctly but stops working and it freezes at the time when I refresh tab. How can I achieve this ?

Here is example Image of this timer
[Boss Countdown Timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVxFN.png)

And here is example of code:

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const BossTimer = ({ boss }) => {
  const { name, race, elements, bossRespawnTime, image, raceImage } = boss;
  const timerKey = `timer_${name}`;
  const storedTime =
    parseInt(window.localStorage.getItem(timerKey)) || bossRespawnTime;
  const [remainingTime, setRemainingTime] = useState(storedTime);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;

    if (isRunning) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setRemainingTime((prevRemainingTime) => {
          const newTime = prevRemainingTime - 1;
          window.localStorage.setItem(timerKey, newTime.toString()); // Store the new time in local storage
          return newTime;
        });
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isRunning, timerKey]);

  const startTimer = () => {
    setIsRunning(true);
  };

  const resetTimer = () => {
    setIsRunning(false);
    setRemainingTime(bossRespawnTime);
    window.localStorage.removeItem(timerKey); // Remove the timer from local storage
  };

  const formatTime = (timeInSeconds) => {
    const hours = Math.floor(Math.abs(timeInSeconds) / 3600);
    const minutes = Math.floor((Math.abs(timeInSeconds) % 3600) / 60);
    const seconds = Math.abs(timeInSeconds) % 60;

    return `${timeInSeconds < 0 ? "-" : ""}${hours}:${String(minutes).padStart(
      2,
      "0"
    )}:${String(seconds).padStart(2, "0")}`;
  };

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div className="boss-info">
          <img src={image} alt={`${name} Image`} width="50" height="50" />
          <span className="boss-name">{name}</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src={raceImage} alt={`${race} Image`} width="30" height="30" />
        <span className="boss-race">{race}</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div className="element-image">
          {elements.map((element, index) => (
            <img
              key={index}
              src={element}
              alt={`Element ${index + 1}`}
              width="20"
              height="20"
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div className="timer">
          <span>{formatTime(remainingTime)}</span>
          <div className="timer-buttons">
            <button onClick={startTimer}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={resetTimer}>Restart</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};

function App() {
  const bosses = [
    {
      name: "Архон",
      bossRespawnTime: 4 * 60 * 60 + 20 * 60,
      image:URL_OF_IMAGE_1,
      race: "Undead",
      elements: ["URL_OF_ELEMENT_2_1"],
      ,
      raceImage:  "URL_OF_RACE_IMAGE_2",    },
    {
      name: "Boss 2",
      bossRespawnTime: 3 * 60 * 60 + 15 * 60,
      image: "URL_OF_IMAGE_2",
      race: "Undead",
      elements: ["URL_OF_ELEMENT_2_1"],
      raceImage: "URL_OF_RACE_IMAGE_2",
    },
    // Add more bosses with different information as needed
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Boss Timers</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Boss Info</th>
            <th>Race</th>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>Timer/Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {bosses.map((boss, index) => (
            <BossTimer key={index} boss={boss} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;```


I tried to set data in local storage. It keeps it but countdown stops working and when I go to site with another device timer is set on default time as I gave it to code
````

Comment: Try and store the planned end time, not the remaining time. This way you can calculate the remaining time on the fly.

Comment: Doing `prevRemainingTime - 1` this is the most unreliable solution that exist

Comment: I am kind new in this thing so just tried this way.